# C++ error: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

My issue I assume is with &line.at(0). I had an error with it before, but dereferencing it took away the error. I am not sure why that is, as I was under the impression that my getline function would return the first line (one integer value that is the size of an array to sort), and the next would be a string of integers, separated by a space, that you put into the array that you then sort.

```
/* This Program is the main entry point
 * in order to call insertion_sort
 */

#include <insertion_sort.cpp>
#include <utils.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    /**
     * YOUR CODE HERE
     * 1. Check for the number of arguments.
     * Only proceed if the number of argument is correct,
     * We will only check for ./main [INPUT_FILE] [OUTPUT_FILE]
     * 
     */
    if(argc == 3){

    /**
     * YOUR CODE HERE
     * 2. Read the file [INPUT_FILE]
     * 
     */

        ifstream fin;
        ofstream fout;
        fin.open(argv[1]);
        if (!fin.is_open()){
            return -1;
        }
        string line;
        string line2;
        getline(fin, line);
        getline(fin, line2);
        int size = atoi(&line.at(0));
        int iterator = 0;
        
        
        
    /**
     * YOUR CODE HERE
     * 3. Build IntSequence
     */
    
        IntSequence unsorted_array;
        unsorted_array.length = size;
        unsorted_array.array = new int[unsorted_array.length];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < line2.length(); i++){
            if (&line2.at(i) != " "){
                unsorted_array.array[iterator] = atoi(&line2.at(i));
                iterator += 1;
            }
        

    /**
     * YOUR CODE HERE
     * 4. Run Insertion Sort
     */
    
        insertion_sort(unsorted_array);

    /**
     * YOUR CODE HERE
     * 5. Write the file into [OUTPUT_FILE]
     */
    
        fout.open(argv[2]);
        if (fout.is_open()){
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < unsorted_array.length; i++){
                fout << unsorted_array.array[i] << " ";
            }
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
        
    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check if the string `line` is not empty before calling std::string::at().

Answer (score 0):

In this line it seems that you are comparing a `char *` to another `char *`.

```
if (&line2.at(i) != " "){
```

I think that you intended to compare a `char` to a `char` instead, in other words check that the current character is not a space to then convert it to an integer.

```
if (line2.at(i) != ' '){
```

Otherwise your expression inside your `if` statement would likely return `true` even when you didn't count on it returning true, potentially overflowing your `int` array due to adding duplicate integers, since `atoi` ignores whitespace.